# Jenkinsfile: Why `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method` is not caught?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following code in the Jenkinsfile which calls an "optional" method, and if it does not exists it just shall print a message

```
...
try {
   verifyDeployment(pipelineParams)
} catch (err) {
   echo "[INFO] No `verifyDeployment` defined, thus ignoring this step"
}
...
```

However when I run the pipeline the `catch` seems not to work at I get the following error:

> `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'verifyDeployment' found among steps`

What do I miss?

Comment: You are using a wrong syntax. See the correct groovy syntax for catching exceptions: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_exception_handling.htm

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize that the syntax is wrong as in some cases it seem to work. Interestingly also examples show same syntax as I am using
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/

Comment: Please add your comment as answer, so I can accept it and you will get some reward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a wrong groovy syntax. 
See the correct groovy syntax for catching exceptions: [Syntax catching exceptions](http://tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_exception_handling.htm)

```
try { 
   //Protected code 
} catch(ExceptionName e1) {
   //Catch block 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you need to explicitly catch `NoSuchMethodError` as follows

```java
...
try {
   verifyDeployment(pipelineParams)
} catch (NoSuchMethodError ex) {
   echo "[INFO] No `verifyDeployment` defined, thus ignoring this step"
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also be more generic with the catching type and

```
catch (Throwable ex)
```

See the type hierarchy:

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html

But be sure to read up on "catch throwable practice" and decide if it's right for you.  I sometimes catch throwable only for logging followed by a rethrow.